# Probability (expectation)

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose there are 20 different types of coupons and suppose that each time one obtain a coupon is equal likely to be any one of the type compute the expected number of different types that are contained in a set of 10 coupons?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have done the question I have 2 different answers in my mind I can't judge which one is correct.but after posting this question I am seeing many more different approaches which seems to be correct and could justify my self what the answer is

Answer (score 1):

Each type has an equal probability  of being picked/not picked in each draw, thus

P(type *i* not picked in a draw) $=\frac{19}{20}=0.95$

so P( type *i* not picked in $10$ draws) $= 0.95^{10}$

and P(type *i* picked in 10 draws)$=1 - 0.95^{10}$

By linearity of expectation, expected number of types collected

$$ =\sum_{i=1}^{20}(1- 0.95^{10})\approx 8$$

Comment: I don't think it is true because when are  making 10 draws the expected value of no of different draws doesn't exceed 10 logically

Comment: I had misunderstood question. Have put up revised answer.

Comment: Aren't you satisfied with this answer ? I am pretty certain that this is correct.

Comment: Your writing that the probability of picking every card in 10 draws is same but probability of 2 draw with effected by first and so on

Comment: The question clearly states that **"...suppose that each time one obtain a coupon is equal likely to be any one of the type..."** This amounts to drawing from an infinite pool $\equiv$ drawing with replacement.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

$20^{10}$ = The number of different ways 10 coupons can be selected from 20 types, assuming repetition is allowed.

The number of ways all 10 coupons are same = $^{20}C_1 \times ^{19} C_0$
The number of ways 9 coupons are same = $^{20}C_1 \times ^{19} C_1$
The number of ways 8 coupons are same = $^{20}C_1 \times ^{19} C _2$
The number of ways 7 coupons are same = ${20}C_1 \times ^{19} C_3$
.
.
.
The number of ways 0 coupons are same = $^{20} C_{10}$

$N = ^{20}C_1 \times ^{19}C_0 +  ^{20}C_1 \times ^{19}C_1 + ^{20}C_1 \times ^{19}C_2 + ... + ^{20}C_1 \times ^{19}C_9 + ^{20}C_{10} = 20^{10}$

X = The number of coupons that are different.

$E(X) = \frac{^{20} C_1 \times ^{19}C_0 \times 0 + ^{20}C_1 \times ^{19}C_1 \times 1 + ... + ^{20}C_1 \times ^{19} C_9 \times  9 + ^{20} C_{10} \times 10}{20^{10}}$

**EDIT 1 START**

It seems my answer is incorrect. I must've misunderstood the question.

I've calculated the expected value for random variable X = the number of different coupons in the 10 selected. Is the answer correct for this interpretation of the question?

**EDIT 1 END**

Comment: There is a small mistake I my question I intended to ask expected value but I have overseen the question I am very sorry about it.Now I edited my question can you please please check it and do it once again

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Is it correct now? @trueblueanil?

Comment: This still doesn't work - first off, you are off by one, since if all $10$ coupons were the same, there would be $1$ type, not zero.  But moreover, there are many different decompositions where there are two specific coupon types, for example, there could be a $5$-$5$ split, or a $7$-$3$ split, etc... and of course the order of could be permuted as well.

Comment: @MW, Please note that my random variable X = the number of coupons that *stand out*. With all 10 coupons same there are 0 coupons that *stand out*. Nevertheless, true, I should count a set with all coupons same. Gracias.